# SEO smart plugin not working for words ending with ä, ö, å

Tags: plugins, links

Custom keywords don't get linked if  words end with  this letters : ä, ö, å

It works if those letters are inbetween. any idea how to fix this?

Custom Keywords :

> 1. meäts, www.google.com        - works
> 2. tillhört, www.rediff.com     - works
> 3. Elektrobitissä, www.git.com  - does not work
> 4. tillhrtö, www.rediff.com     - does not work

So out of the above keywords, 1 and 2 works.
3 and 4 does not work.
If word ends with those special letters, word is not linked otherwise if letter appears in any position except last, it works.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-automatic-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is using string functions for single-byte encodings:

```
$url = substr($line, $lastDelimiterPos + 1 );
$keywords = substr($line, 0, $lastDelimiterPos);
```

But in WordPress everything is encoded in UTF-8, a multi-byte encoding. So each time you have a character in your keywords that needs more than one byte, something gets lost.

File a bug report and ask the author to read [this article](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/). He will use the mbstring functions then. Probably. :)